# How to check if the WPF Window is closed or not from another WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm new to WPF Environment and I would like to know how can I handle the Window_closed event , I mean how can I check if the window is closed or no from another Window form,  I have just written some code:

```
 // Window form 1
           
            for (int k = 0; k <= listgrid.Count - 1; k++)
            {
                test  test = new test(listgrid[0]); // the new form ( Window form 2 )
                test.Show();
                if (test.IsClosed) // I need to check here if the window form 2 is closed or not
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OKK Is closed after  " + test.IsClosed);
                    test.Show();
                }

            }
```

```
// Second form
  public partial class test : Window
    {
        public bool test_close;

        public test(GridModel gridModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
 
        }

        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //      base.Close();
            IsClosed = true;
            Console.WriteLine( " Ok " +IsClosed);
        }
        public bool IsClosed { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            IsClosed = true;
        }
```

Comment: There's a few things to unpack first: 1) Why are you showing multiple windows in a for loop? That is unlikely to be a nice user experience. 2) Why are you re-showing the form after it is closed?

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: @DGrowns I would like to show only one element in the next form not two, the second element should be shown when I close the new form , for that reason I'm searching for a trick to get the event of window is closed ( form 2 ) to open a new form that show the second element

Comment: @KlausGütter what do you mean?

Comment: So you have written already some code. I just asked whether this code already works and you are asking for "better" options. Or if your code does not achieve what you want.

Comment: No , my code does not achieve what I want, I'm searching for a solution.

Comment: @abdou93 The simplest answer would be to perform ShowDialog() instead of Show() as this will block the for loop from continuing until the current window has been closed. Is that suitable? If not, then I have another suggestion but it is more convoluted.

Comment: I have add the event and I have fixed it thank you

Comment: @abdou93 Great. I've posted this as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Application.Current.Windows.OfType().FirstOrDefault()** to get the second window during runtime, then you can check it is open or not.I will show you the detailed steps in my demo:

The code for MainWindow.xaml(as first page):

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This is the first Window" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Open Child Window：" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287" Height="39" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="OpenButton_Click" />
    <Button Content="Check child " Width="287" Height="39" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The code for ainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var oldWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<SecondWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (oldWindow != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Child_Window is open!");
        }else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Child_Window is closed");

        }
    }

    private void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondWindow newWindow = new SecondWindow();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
```

The code for SecondWindow.xaml is simpler which only has one line code:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="This is second Window!" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

When you run the project, you can get the below result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to perform ShowDialog() instead of Show() as this will block the for loop from continuing until the current window has been closed.

The Microsoft documentation states:

> When a Window class is instantiated, it is not visible by default. ShowDialog shows the window, disables all other windows in the application, and returns only when the window is closed. This type of window is known as a modal window.

[More about ShowDialog here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1)